# How to read xlsx blob into pandas from Azure function in python

Tags: python, pandas, azure, azure-functions, blob

I am reading in .xslx data from a blob in an azure function. My code looks something like this:

```
def main(techdatablob: func.InputStream, crmdatablob: func.InputStream, outputblob: func.Out[func.InputStream]):

    # Load in the tech and crm data
    crm_data = pd.read_excel(crmdatablob.read().decode('ISO-8859-1'))
    tech_data = pd.read_excel(techdatablob.read().decode('ISO-8859-1'))
```

The issue is when I try to decode the files, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Protocol not known: PK...
```

And a lot of strange characters after the "...". Any thoughts on how to properly read in these files?

Comment: @BowmanZhu This is a continuation of [a question on reading in multiple blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66129665/input-multiple-blobs-into-azure-function-python?noredirect=1#comment116916394_66129665) that you may be able to help with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer to my code, it seems that you don't need to add `decode('ISO-8859-1')`:

```py
import logging
import pandas as pd
import azure.functions as func


def main(techdatablob: func.InputStream, crmdatablob: func.InputStream, outputblob: func.Out[func.InputStream]):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {techdatablob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {techdatablob.length} bytes")

    # Load in the tech and crm data
    crm_data = pd.read_excel(crmdatablob.read())
    logging.info(f"{crm_data}")
    tech_data = pd.read_excel(techdatablob.read())
    logging.info(f"{tech_data}")
```

**Note:** Your `function.json` should look like this. Otherwise, an error will occur.

```
{
      "name": "techdatablob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "path1/{name}",
      "connection": "example"
    },
    {
      "name": "crmdatablob",
      "dataType": "binary",
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "path2/data.xlsx",
      "connection": "example"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      "path": "path3/out.xlsx",
      "connection": "example"
    }
```

The difference between this and your `function.json` is that you are missing a `dataType` attribute.

[image]

My test result is like this, there are seems to be no problems.

[image]

Comment: Amazing! This worked for me. Very bewildered that this wasn't anywhere to be found in the docs that I read. Cheers!